# Passing variables from javascript to php for geolocation function

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey guys I want the longitude and latitude I get from the javascript code to pass it to the php variables $lat and $lng so I can get the $city and use it in my sql query(query not included). Below is my code. Please help

```
        <html>

<head>
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        document.write("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {

  var latitude= position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude= position.coords.longitude); 

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()"></body>
</html>
<?php

 function getaddress($lat,$lng)
  {
     $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
     $json = @file_get_contents($url);
     $data=json_decode($json);
     $status = $data->status;
     if($status=="OK")
     {
       return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
  }
   $lat= 33.568711799999996; //latitude
  $lng= 35.3800354; //longitude
  $address= getaddress($lat,$lng);
  if($address)
  {
    // Delimiters may be slash, or comma
    //$date = "04/30/1973";
    list($address, $street, $city) = split('[,-]', $address);
    echo "Address: $address; Street: $street; City: $city <br />\n";

  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not found";
  }
?>
```

Comment: What result does your code produce, what result do you expect it to produce?

Comment: Are the HTML and the PHP in different files? You would need to use Ajax to send the JS data to PHP.

Comment: They are in the same file. I want var longitude and latitude to be passed to $lng and $lat

Answer (score 1):

You should move your PHP script to another file for e.g. `script.php` than with jquery get

```
$.get( "script.php", { lat: "123", lon: "321" }, function( data ) {
    alert( data ); // or you can insert result text to your block
});
```

And start your PHP script with this:

```
if(isset($_GET['lat']) && isset($_GET['lon']))
```

P.S. Don't forget to include jquery lib

Comment: This answer does solve the issue. However, you can  make the Ajax call in vanilla JS if jquery isn't used anywhere else in your app. Including a full and bloated js-lib just for one Ajax-call is overkill.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson There are many solutions of this problem, thats the way I solve it.

Comment: My point was that recommending using jQuery (if it isn't already in use) just to make one single ajax call is silly. You should always try and keep your application as light as possible and not just include bloated libraries when there's no need to.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You can add ajax only - http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ if you have another solution without using additional libraries you can post it here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @MagnusEriksson nice guide if you want to replace 3 lines of code by 30

Comment: It's not about how many lines _you_ write. It's about how many lines the users need to download (and you actually only need about 11 lines). Downloading jQuery through the service you linked to and only select Ajax, is still 8319 lines of code. Then even 30 lines is _way_ better. Don't be lazy at the users expense. Here's another post for you: https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Dude, just create another answer and let the author select what he want. Both solutions works.

Comment: Why? Your answer is still correct. (I'm actually the one that up voted this). I just pointed out that including jQuery for one Ajax was overkill. The OP (and future visitors) can then make an educated decision.